# google sheet image() function updating (slow, erratic, laggy)

Tags: google-sheets

Have been using google sheets for many years. Powerful and free so I like it.

Recently the image() function updating has been erratic or laggy.

Using the function in PC with many browers, chrome, firefox or edge etc, the pic failed to diplay after many minutes. Erratic, sometimes faster, sometimes longer.

However when using android phone or tablet, always display within about 10 sec. I attached an image of my spreadsheet with PC and tablet side by side

Anyone facing the same problem?
Anyway to solve it?
Is google restricting bandwith or is it a bug?

Thank u guys for reading my post:)

[image]

Comment: Hello @tangkb, the `IMAGE` function works just fine for me. Have you tried using another image to see if that works? Moreover, do you have lots of data in your Sheet? Cheers!

Comment: It's not that the function is not working, it is that googlesheet is unstable. Maybe because I use the spreadsheet everyday. I have a formula to load different charts by changing the stock code. But strangely it loads always when using android

Answer (score 0):

*The fact that you use Sheets everyday has nothing to do with the way it works.*

Sheets on a computer can be slow due to various reasons - large amounts of data stored, using functions which make use of other Spreadsheets and even connectivity issues.

The fact that the `IMAGE` function works on one device as expected and not on another one can be due to many reasons as well. Since this issue seems particular to your situation you might want to take a look onto your data from the Spreadsheet and how can you improve the performance.

*What you can do to improve performance:*

- Try to use close-ranges when using formulas and such. For example, use `A1:C3` if the data is stored in that range instead of `A:C`.
- Certain functions can also slow the performance of a Spreadsheet, especially the so-called *volatile functions* such as `NOW()`, `TODAY()`, `RAND()` since these functions refresh every time there's a change in the Sheets.
- `IMPORTRANGE`, `IMPORTHTML`, `IMPORTFEED`, `IMPORTDATA` and `IMPORTXML` are also known to recalculate; for the `IMPORTANGE` the time is of 30 minutes and for the others is 1 hour.

**Reference**

- [Sheets Limitations](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en);
- [Formulas Recalculation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515)

Comment: I think the reasons mentioned were not the reason.
Strangely after not working properly for few weeks, the image function is working properly in Window PC environment for the past two days.

Comment: Really hope someone from google is reading this. The image() function loads consistently in Android devices, but is erratic in Windows PC devices. Is this a bug or just Google toggling bandwith to free users?